# Переворачивается картинка на 90 градусов только в Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая проблема. Во всех браузерах картинка отображается нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в Microsoft Edge почему то переворачивается на 90 deg.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталкивался с таким и как решить?

Comment: Из фотки нужно удалить информацию EXIF. Откройте ее в текстовом редакторе и сохраните без EXIF. Подробнее: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF

Comment: Фото загружаются пользователями сервиса. Со стороны бэка наверное надо впилить тогда такой функционал что бы при загрузке фото meta данные затирались.